# Pushing a flattened array to another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So I have:

```
var arr = [1, 2],
    numArr = [3, 4, 5];
// I want arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

So I want to be able to push numArr into arr. But the key point is that I want to do it in place. (meaning that I don't generate a new array and assign it to arr).

Right now I'm using:

```
[].push.apply(arr, numArr);
```

But I was wondering if there's a cleaner alternative using Underscore or native JS.

Comment: For anyone answering, note that [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) does **not** meet the criteria of not generating a new array.

Comment: @Nit: However, generating a new array is usually considered cleaner :-)

Comment: @Bergi Not reasonable if your datasets are large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a cleaner alternative!

```
numArr.forEach(function (x) {
    arr.push(x);
});
```

Note that `apply` stops working at several thousand elements.

Underscore doesn’t have anything to do this, as far as I know (don’t use `_.extend` for it).

Comment: Oh I hate how `numArr.forEach([].push, arr);` is not equivalent…

Comment: Mind commenting on [this jsperf test I just made](http://jsperf.com/array-push-apply-vs-foreach-push)? Did I miss a detail and make an unfair test? As long as the call stack isn't exceeded, the original code the asker posted is faster.

Comment: @Nit: It’s not unfair, but there’s a bit that was probably unintentional: try adding `console.log(a.length)` in the teardown. (The setup runs outside of each test, but there’s still another loop, so the size of the array varies.) You’re right, though; I started writing my answer with a `for` loop, and changed it to `forEach` without updating the next paragraph. `forEach` is considerably slower. (`push.apply` still outperforms `for` in Chrome, anyway, but not in Firefox. http://jsperf.com/array-push-apply-vs-foreach-push/2)